# Display inline block text inside issue

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have been trying out display inline-block, everything worked out great if I didn't add anything into the divs but when I do the div collapsed and I don't know exactly why.

Any idea?

https://jsfiddle.net/giancorzo/ebqoptbd/

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>8 cajas</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="caja"></div>
        <div class="caja-grande">
            <div class="caja inline-block">
                <span>Hola mundo</span>
            </div>
            <div class="caja inline-block">
            </div>
            <div class="caja inline-block">
        CSS:    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="caja inline-block"></div>
        <div class="caja inline-block"></div>
        <div class="caja"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.caja{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}

.inline-block{
    display: inline-block;
}

.caja-grande{
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is due to default vertical alignment of inline elements – `baseline`, the text inside element affects it and pushes div to the bottom. Use `vertical-align: top`, for example, to suppress this behavior.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ebqoptbd/1/)

Comment: Thanks it worked, I also tested it with vertical-align:middle; and it also worked.

Answer (score 3):

`display:inline-block` creates a small gap, so add `font-size:0` to parent. plus add `vertical-align:top` since by default `inline-block` is `baseline`

with all of this you have fixed your issue.

here is the  snippet:

```css
.caja {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}
.caja-grande {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 0
}
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja"></div>
<div class="caja-grande">
  <div class="caja inline-block">
    <span>Hola mundo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="caja inline-block">
  </div>
  <div class="caja inline-block">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="caja inline-block"></div>
<div class="caja inline-block"></div>
<div class="caja"></div>
```

you can find more info (and options on how to solve this in other ways) in this article [**Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements**](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: the font-size:0px fix the gap between inline-blocks, but what actually fix the text is the vertical-align:top like suslov said.

Comment: I found this tutorial that talks about the gap in inline-blocks https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: this tutorial I mentioned in my answer same as `vertical-align:top`, I just gave you a complete answer

Answer (score 2):

Use `overflow: hidden` at `.inline-block` to make this work.

```
.inline-block{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This also works but adds a extra margin to the bottom

Comment: its not a margin its the space of the `inline-box` that creates by default . and you can fix it by adding `font-size: 0` to the parent container