# Why my div block will shift when has some content inside?

Tags: html, css

```css
.role_wrapper1,.role_wrapper2 {
  display:inline-block;
}


.role_wrapper1 {
  width:200px;
  height:230px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right:6px;
}

.role_wrapper2 {
  width:200px;
  height:230px;
  margin-right:10px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="role_wrapper1">1</div>
<div class="role_wrapper2"></div>
```

Without any content inside div1 , these two will display correctly.
However, when I put some content in div1, the div2 will shift.

Did i missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css display inline block text inside issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417976/css-display-inline-block-text-inside-issue)

Comment: Thanks.I use vertical-align: top to solve this problem. Sorry for duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missing : `float:left`

```css
.role_wrapper1,.role_wrapper2 {
  display:inline-block;
}


.role_wrapper1 {
  width:200px;
  height:230px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right:6px;
  float:left
}

.role_wrapper2 {
  width:200px;
  height:230px;
  margin-right:10px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="role_wrapper1">1hjghjjgj</div>
<div class="role_wrapper2"></div>
```